# Latex formatting problem. Words/terms at the begin of two paragraphs are shifted

Tags: latex

I have a problem with the formatting. I just want to have an empty line between multiple paragraphs starting with the same words. But between some of the paragraphs the length of the terms (identical words and a number) differ. I tried to use `\\` to get the empty line and also tried to use `\bigbreak` and in the following line `\noindent` to avoid paragraph indenting. Without the empty line the problem does not occur.

How to overcome this issue? Please check my code and snapshots:

Method 1: `\\`

```
Hypothesis 1: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite increases the overall density of the composite.\\
Hypothesis 2: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite increases the overall strength of the composite.\\
Hypothesis 3: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite changes the UV-/IR-radiation absorption spectrum and -coefficient significantly.
```

[image: screenshot method 1 - compiled output]

Method 2: `\bigbreak \noindent`

```
Hypothesis 1: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite increases the overall density of the composite.\bigbreak
\noindent Hypothesis 2: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite increases the overall strength of the composite.\bigbreak
\noindent Hypothesis 3: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite changes the UV-/IR-radiation absorption spectrum and -coefficient significantly.
```

[image: screenshot method 2 - compiled output]

Weirdly I get two different faulty outcomes. Any advice?
I use Overleaf.

Comment: I absolutely do not have this problem. But with small colums, TeX formatting algorithm tries to balance white spaces among all words. I think you can suppress this behavior by using \mbox{Hypothesis 1:}. But you should post a fully compilable document with all the packages so that people can reproduce your problem and help you efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

@Alain

Thanks for your solution approach, it looks a bit better, now, but still the following text is shifted a bit. please check the following source code. I deleted almost everything, as of copyright obligations. First with \mbox, then as before without.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}


% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{ARP_references.bib}    %your file created using JabRef

% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
% A popular package from the American Mathematical Society that provides
% many useful and powerful commands for dealing with mathematics.

% *** PDF, URL AND HYPERLINK PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{url}
% url.sty was written by Donald Arseneau. It provides better support for
% handling and breaking URLs. url.sty is already installed on most LaTeX
% systems. The latest version and documentation can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url
% Basically, \url{my_url_here}.

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\usepackage{graphicx}  %needed to include png, eps figures

\usepackage{float}  % used to fix location of images i.e.\begin{figure}[H]

\usepackage{textcomp} % für Grad-Zeichen

\usepackage{textgreek} % greek symbols in text

\usepackage{comment} % whole paragraph comments

\usepackage{enumitem} % for enumeration properties

\raggedbottom % avoids silly space after sections or titles (found on internet)

\begin{document}

% paper title
% Do not put math or special symbols in the title.


% author names and IEEE memberships
% note positions of commas and nonbreaking spaces ( ~ ) LaTeX will not break
% a structure at a ~ so this keeps an author's name from being broken across
% two lines.
% use \thanks{} to gain access to the first footnote area
% a separate \thanks must be used for each paragraph as LaTeX2e's \thanks
% was not built to handle multiple paragraphs

\author{}% <-this % stops a space

% The report headers
\markboth{}%do not delete next lines
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for IEEE Journals}

% make the title area


% As a general rule, do not put math, special symbols or citations
% in the abstract or keywords.
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
keywords, temperature, xxxx equation, etc.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
% Here we have the typical use of a "W" for an initial drop letter
% and "RITE" in caps to complete the first word.
% You must have at least 2 lines in the paragraph with the drop letter
% (should never be an issue)

\IEEEPARstart{A}{irlines}  

\section{}


\section{}


\section{Design of Experiments}
Test\\
\mbox{Hypothesis 1:} The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite increases the overall density of the composite.\\\\
\mbox{Hypothesis 2:} The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite increases the overall strength of the composite.\\\\
\mbox{Hypothesis 3:} The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite changes the UV-/IR-radiation absorption spectrum and -coefficient significantly.\\\\

Test\\
Hypothesis 1: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite increases the overall density of the composite.\\\\
Hypothesis 2: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite increases the overall strength of the composite.\\\\
Hypothesis 3: The increase of the ratio of tungsten-trioxide in the composite changes the UV-/IR-radiation absorption spectrum and -coefficient significantly.\\\
\end{document}
```

There is alot of comments, as I use a template recommended by my university.
Thx- Kaydon